# Do multiple Python interpreters on a server share pages in memory?

Tags: python, operating-system, multiprocessing

One of the more clever things Android does to conserve memory and increase startup time is share pages between multiple Dalvik interpreters by forking processes from a the `zygote` process. When an application loads, the static, readonly library code pages are shared between the parent and the child.

Does python or multiprocessing do anything on these lines?

Comment: On Linux, if you use `fork` to create the processes, they will share read-only memory segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an operating system feature (not a language feature) that at least Linux and probably most OSes offer. It's nothing unique to Android.

So yes, Python and multiprocessing do essentially the same thing if you are running on Linux, simply because they use `fork()` to spawn additional processes.

Answer (score 1):

Not on purpose. They let the OS worry about sharing pages between the instances of the library.